# Issue with KnpPaginatorBundle\Helper\Processor router argument

Tags: symfony, knppaginator

I have a problem: cache file and KnpPaginatorBundle. I am getting a weird error only on the prod server:

> PHP Catchable fatal error:  Argument 1 passed to Knp\Bundle\PaginatorBundle\Helper\Processor::__construct() must be an instance of Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\Helper\RouterHelper, instance of BeSimple\I18nRoutingBundle\Routing\Router given, called in /.../app/cache/prod/appProdProjectContainer.php on line 809 and defined in /.../vendor/knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle/Knp/Bundle/PaginatorBundle/Helper/Processor.php on line 27

I got it when I installed a new bundle via the composer and I did **'composer update -o'**.
Before 'composer update' command, I had in appProdProjectContainer.php on line 809:

```
 return $this->services['knp_paginator.helper.processor'] = new \Knp\Bundle\PaginatorBundle\Helper\Processor($this->get('templating.helper.router'), $this->get('translator.default'));
```

And it worked fine on the localhost and on the prod server. But after 'composer update' I have this (the same line)

```
return $this->services['knp_paginator.helper.processor'] = new \Knp\Bundle\PaginatorBundle\Helper\Processor($this->get('be_simple_i18n_routing.router'), $this->get('translator.default'));
```

It works fine on the localhost (I have never got any issue) but I get this error only on the prod server.
I cleaned cache many times, I checked configuration in config.yml, no success. So, I put comments on these lines and the prod works now

```
// $apcLoader = new ApcClassLoader('prniszone', $loader);
// $loader->unregister();
// $apcLoader->register(true);
```

What can I do to fix this issue on the prod server?

Prod : php 5.4.44, opCache + APCu, sf 2.4.1 (I have 2.4.1 on the local,too and it works there), the same configuration on both servers.

Comment: Do you have the latest vendor files on your server?

Comment: Yes, I copied (3-4 times) whole vendor folder with all files.

Comment: So, no success. It is weird that only I have this issue.  What do you have as value   in your appProdProjectContainer.php ? be_simple_i18n_routing.router ?